# Angular 2 - Auth0 User Profile, undefined

Tags: angular, undefined, auth0

I try to use Auth0 in my Angular 2 project. I'm learning it form [Auth0 website](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/03-user-profile). My problem is with the user profile. After I log in, I call on ngOnInit approximately the same method as in the example from the website:

```
if (this.auth.isAuthenticated()) {
    if (this.auth.userProfile) {
        this.profile = this.auth.userProfile;
    } else {
        this.auth.getProfile((err, profile) => {
            this.profile = profile;
        });
    }

    this.auth.alreadyExists(this.profile.sub);
}
```

The problem is the `this.auth.alreadyExists(this.profile.sub);` method's parameter `this.profile.sub`.

The error message is:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined.

If I write in the HTML file `{{profile?.sub}}` and delete the `this.auth.alreadyExists(this.profile.sub);` method, it displays with no problem the user_id.

I don't know where is the mistake.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since getProfile is asynchronous, profile.sub doesn't exist yet when you call alreadyExists. If you move the call to alreadyExists up into the getProfile callback then you should be fine.

Comment: I have an other problem now. I've put the alreadyExists method in the getProfile method and now I get this error message: Cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

Comment: 'userId' is a property of my model

Comment: I'd need to see your `alreadyExists` method. Might be best to post another question :)